# Proof that bn is monotonically decreasing and bounded from below

Tags: sequences-and-series

The general term of the sequence:

$$b_n=\frac{3n+2}{ 2^n}$$

The $b_n>0$ and $\frac{b_{n+1} }{ b_n} < 1$ , so $b_n$ ( ↓ )

and if $$\lim_{n → ∞ } b_n = L$$

then bounded from below.

Is that correct ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can observe that the sequence is bounded from below ($b_n>0$) and monotonically decreasing ($b_{n+1}<b_n$) therefore it has finite limit according to [monotonic convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).